# Shim a jQuery plugin with browserify

Tags: javascript, jquery, gruntjs, browserify, shim

Hi I'm using the grunt browserify task to setup my code, I have shimmed in jQuery and I'm now trying to include jquery.tablesorter.

Can jquery plugins be used with browserify in this way?

```
shim: {
    jquery: {
        path: 'lib/bower/jquery/jquery.js',
        exports: '$'
    },
    'jquery.tablesorter': {
        path: 'lib/bower/jquery.tablesorter/js/jquery.tablesorter.js',
        exports: 'tablesorter',
        depends: {
            jquery: '$',
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You may try by doing this:

```
shim: {
    jquery: {
        path: 'lib/bower/jquery/jquery.js',
        exports: '$'
    },
    'jquery.tablesorter': {
        path: 'lib/bower/jquery.tablesorter/js/jquery.tablesorter.js',
        exports: null,
        depends: {
            jquery: '$',
        }
    }
}
```

If the above is not working, you can try this:

```
shim: {
    jquery: {
        path: 'lib/bower/jquery/jquery.js',
        exports: null
    },
    'jquery.tablesorter': {
        path: 'lib/bower/jquery.tablesorter/js/jquery.tablesorter.js',
        exports: null,
        depends: {
            jquery: 'jQuery',
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It does not give me error but during require call it gives me a blank object
var $ = require('$'),sorter = require('jquery-tablesorter');
console.log($,sorter); // it consoles {} {}

Comment: @kundu may I know which grunt-browserify version are u using? This solution only works for an earlier version.

Comment: @Lim I am using browserify v5.9.1. For the newer version what should be the way out.

Comment: see if this article is helpful to you http://aeflash.com/2014-05/grunt-browserify-2-x-update.html

Comment: Where does `shim`come from? Current browserify docs say to use `browserify-shim` https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you dont need to use "browserify-shim" section in package.json if you use this extention.

You can do like here [Using Browserify with jQuery Plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24707406/using-browserify-with-jquery-plugins)

I've tried it and it works.

**Example**

package.json

```
"browserify": {
    "transform": ["browserify-shim"]
},
"browser": {
     "jQuery.translit": "./public_html/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.translit.js"
},
"browserify-shim": {
    "jQuery": "global:jQuery"
}
```

JS file:

```
var $ = require("jQuery"),
    translit = require("jQuery.translit"),  //don't use this variable      
    heading = require("./helper/heading.js");
$.transliterate("parameter"); //use as regular jQuery plugin instead
```

Comment: Not elegant but I used this trick and it works. You don't have to assign to a variable, just call `require("x")`

Comment: Yes, you're right. Also solution from Ian Lim may be better.

Answer (score 0):

Its much easier to require global.JQuery and then require your module, it require no changes to package.json:

```
global.jQuery = require('jquery');
require('tipso');
```