# How to load jQuery mobile in browserify project?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, gulp, browserify, browserify-shim

I'm trying to load jquery-mobile in my browserify project and getting an error because `this` refers to an empty object instead of the `window` object. Browserify is wrapping jquery-mobile in it's usual wrapper (`function(require, module, exports){ ... }`) but `this` is not in the scope of `window`.

**package.json**

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "animate.css": "^3.1.1",
    "backbone": "^1.1.2",
    "backbone-query-parameters": "git://github.com/jhudson8/backbone-query-parameters",
    "backbone.marionette": "^2.3.1",
    "backbone.radio": "^0.6.0",
    "backbone.storage": "^0.1.0",
    "backbone.syphon": "^0.5.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.1",
    "browserify-swap": "^0.2.1",
    "handlebars": "^1.3.0",
    "jquery": "^2.1.3",
    "jquery-mobile": "^1.4.1",
    "lodash": "^2.4.1",
    "nprogress": "^0.1.6"
  },
  "browser": {
    "bootstrap": "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
    "jquery-mobile": "./node_modules/jquery-mobile/dist/jquery.mobile.js"
  },
  "browserify-shim": {
    "bootstrap": {
      "depends": [
        "jquery:jQuery"
      ]
    },
    "jquery": "$",
    "jquery-mobile" : { "exports": "$.mobile", "depends": [ "jquery:$" ] }
  },
  "browserify-swap": {
    "@packages": [
      "underscore"
    ],
    "dist": {
      "underscore.js$": "lodash"
    }
  },
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "babelify",
      [
        "hbsfy",
        {
          "extensions": [
            "hbs"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "browserify-swap",
      "browserify-shim"
    ]
  }
}
```

**Error Message**

> **jquery.mobile.js:14931** Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'jQuery' of undefined

**Then I found moduleify**

I found [moduleify](https://github.com/pluma/moduleify) after a bit of googling and tried to use that in my *package.json* for jquery-mobile but I get an error. This is my updated transform configuration with moduleify:

```
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "babelify",
      [
        "hbsfy",
        {
          "extensions": [
            "hbs"
          ]
        }
      ],
      [
        "moduleify",
        [
          "jquery.mobile"
        ]
      ],
      "browserify-swap",
      "browserify-shim"
    ]
  }
```

Doing this gives me an error with moduleify:

> moduleify/index.js:9
>   var rules = Array.isArray(aliases) ? aliases : Object.keys(aliases).map(fu

Anyone have any suggestions on how to make `this` reference `window`? I feel like I'm on the right track but not sure what to do next. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Including JQuery Mobile in a Node JS project with Browserify](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21428993/including-jquery-mobile-in-a-node-js-project-with-browserify)

Answer (score 0):

In the first approach you do:

```
"jquery-mobile" : { "exports": "$.mobile", "depends": [ "jquery:$" ] }
```

I think you need to do:

```
"jquery-mobile" : { "exports": "$.mobile", "depends": [ "jquery:jQuery" ] }
```

Comment: I tried that also but `this` remains `undefined`. jQuery mobile is looking for the `window` object to get `window.jQuery` to attach `.mobile` to it. Any other suggestions?