# Using Browserify with jQuery Plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, browserify, browserify-shim

Some brief background: I'm using browserify and browserify-shim (and gulp to build) to create a web app. Prior to this issue, I was `require`ing jquery from npm so I had no issues. Once I started doing some optimization, I realized how massive the bundle was with jQuery included. So now I'm grabbing jQuery from a CDN with the script tag and placing it before the bundle.js file. But I'm having issues declaring jQuery as a global and properly shimming my jQuery plugins in browserify and browserify-shim. When I run gulp to build, I keep getting the same error:

`[gulp] gulp-notify: [Compile Error] module "jquery" not found from "/Volumes/Chetan/Users/cshenoy/Projects/urbanstems-node/app/plugins/jquery.inview.js"`

It seems like browserify-shim isn't picking up on jQuery being a global.

For reference, I'm using the [inview plugin](https://github.com/protonet/jquery.inview).

Here's my package.json with the relevant parts

```
"browser": {
  "inview": "./app/plugins/jquery.inview.js"
},
"browserify-shim": {
  "jquery": "global:jQuery",
  "inview": {
    "depends": [
      "jquery"
    ]
  }
}
```

Let me know what else I can include to help diagnose the error.

Comment: I'm curious about going the opposite direction. When you `require('jquery')` from npm, how were you able to expose it globally so plugins still worked?

Comment: I didn't expose it globally when I installed it from npm. The value for jquery inside browserify-shim would be $ or jQuery. Then all your jQuery-dependent plugins would be listed below it with the depends field listing jquery.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out you don't need to declare every jQuery plugin under `browserify-shim` if it only depends on jQuery. I just deleted the inview entry and everything works fine.