# ES6 import – jQuery is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, browserify

I'm using Gulp and Browserify for my build process, except I'm having trouble using third party jQuery plugins – showing error `jQuery is not defined`

The following is my file structure.

***app.js***

```
import $ from 'jquery'
import plugin from 'jquery-plugin'
```

***jquery-plugin.js***

```
(function($) {

    // Plugin code here

}(jQuery));
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You'll [need to shim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21265814/shim-a-jquery-plugin-with-browserify) those modules. Most jQuery plugins don't support UMD/CJS/AMD so Browserify doesn't know how to locate dependencies

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you need use './'

`import $ from 'jquery'
import plugin from './jquery-plugin'`

**EDITED, my new answer below:**

Try this way:

`import * as jqueryPlugin from 'jquery-plugin'`

Comment: He is importing from node_modules so './' is not required. we use './' when importing files from relative directories.

Comment: You are right... maybe he can use this way `import * as` for example: `import * as _ from "lodash"`