# "jQuery is not defined" after require/import when use ES6 with Webpack 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, webpack-4

I am using Webpack 4 for the build process of my React app. 
My app uses jQuery and I want to `import` jQuery plugin but get the following error:

```
Failed to compile.

./jquery-plugin.js
  Line 3:  'jQuery' is not defined  no-undef
```

I've tried the methods described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39820703/1335142) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39661831/1335142) but neither helped me.

**// app.js**

```
import $ from 'jquery';
// import './jquery-plugin.js';
window.$ = window.jQuery = $;

require('./jquery-plugin.js');
```

**// jquery-plugin.js**

```
(function($) {
  // Plugin code
})(jQuery);
```

If I understand [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30331983/1335142) works correctly in the previous Webpack versions.

If I add `import jQuery from 'jquery'` to `jquery-plugin.js` for test it works fine but I cannot do this since it is 3rd party plugin.

Does anyone have ideas how to make jQuery visible globally in Webpack 4?

UPD:

I use [react-app-rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired) for override Webpack config. Here is my config:

**// config-overrides.js**

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = function override(config, env) {
  //do stuff with the webpack config...

  config.module.rules.push({
    // Exposes jQuery for use outside Webpack build
    test: require.resolve('jquery'),
    use: [{
      loader: 'expose-loader',
      options: 'jQuery'
    },{
      loader: 'expose-loader',
      options: '$'
    }]
  });

  config.plugins.push(
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    //provide jquery in all the ways 3rd party plugins might look for it (note that window.$/window.jQuery will not actually set it on the window, which is cool)
    '$': 'jquery',
    'jQuery': 'jquery',
    'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
    'window.$': 'jquery'
  }));

  config.resolve = {
    alias: {
      'jquery-ui': 'jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.js'
    },
  };

  return config;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to let webpack know it's a global:

```
import { ProvidePlugin } from 'webpack';
```

and then in the `plugins` entry of your config:

```
plugins: [ new ProvidePlugin({$: 'jquery', jQuery: 'jquery'}) ],
```

that should fix the issue in `jquery-plugin.js` and you also won't need to import `jquery` anywhere

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: `window.jQuery` and `window.$` in the `ProvidePlugin` config are redundant. The error message you're getting looks like an eslint issue - make sure `$` and `jQuery` are in the `globals` section of your eslint config

Comment: I've created `.eslintrc` in project root, added `{
  "env": {
    "jquery": true
  },
  "globals": {
    "jQuery": true,
    "$": true
  }
}`, re-run `npm start` but nothing changed. Maybe, did you mean something else under *make sure $ and jQuery are in the globals section of your eslint config*?

Comment: No, that's what I meant. Is `jquery` in your `package.json`?

Comment: Yes, I have `"jquery": "^3.3.1",`

Comment: have you tried removing `window.jQuery` and `window.$` form the `ProvidePlugin` config?

Comment: Yes, I've removed these two lines. I also was trying different settings in my configuration and nothing helped me. Maybe does it works something else in Webpack 4?